# How to fill different values to two different columns in a subsetted data at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to fill columns `'level'` and `'class'` with respective values as `'2'` and `'1'` of subsetted data at once:

```
data[(data["Main_Pressure"]<100) & data["Return_Pressure"]<200][['level','class']] = "2","1"
```

After executing the above line Python console the columns `'level'` and `'class'` were not replaced with `'2'` and `'1'`.

How to achieve this in a single line in Python?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, and I am puzzled about why you would want to. What is your objection to having two assignment statements, one for the key `'level'` and one for the key `'class'`? This will do it in one line, but that is not what I think you meant: `data[(data["Main_Pressure"]<100) & data["Return_Pressure"]<200]['level'],data[(data["Main_Pressure"]<100) & data["Return_Pressure"]<200]['class'] = "2","1"`.

Comment: My objective was to assign class and level values when the main pressure as well as return pressure were less than certain numbers in the data

Comment: I still don't see why that has to happen in a single statement. If the dict `data` could be changed between the two assignment statements by another process, then you need to put a lock around your pair of assignments.